# Unused structure elements in regmatch_t array are not -1

Tags: regular-expression, c

The [man page for regcomp and regexec](https://linux.die.net/man/3/regcomp) indicates that, "Any unused structure elements will contain the value -1."

Yet, in logic that checks the value of `rm_so` after my last match, that doesn't seem to be the case. It seems to be equal to 0:

```
#include <stdlib.h>                                              
#include <stdio.h>                                               
#include <string.h>                                              
#include <sys/types.h>                                           
#include <regex.h>                                                                                         

#define MATCH_CNT   4                                            


void print_matches(regmatch_t matches[])                         
{                                                                
  printf("Regexec successful.\n");                               
  int i = 0;                                                     
  for(; i < MATCH_CNT; i++)                                      
  {                            
    //########### HERE'S THE RUB ####################                                  
    if(matches[i].rm_so != -1)                                    
    {                                                            
      printf("Match %i; Beginning:\t%i\n", i, matches[i].rm_so); 
      printf("Match %i; End:\t\t%i\n", i, matches[i].rm_eo);     
    }                                                            
  }                                                              
}                                                                

int main(int argc, char *argv[])                                 
{                                                                
  if(argc != 3)                                                  
    fprintf(stderr, "retester <pattern> <string>\n");            

  char *pat = argv[1];                                           
  char *str = argv[2];                                           

  regex_t compreg;                                               
  memset(&compreg, 0, sizeof(regex_t));                          

  regmatch_t matches[MATCH_CNT];                                 
  memset(&matches, 0, MATCH_CNT*sizeof(regmatch_t));           
  int matchcnt = -1;                                             

  char *errbuff;                                                 

 printf("Trying to match with extended regex...\n");                  
 int compret = -2;                                                        
 //set REG_EXTENDED flag                                              
 if((compret = regcomp(&compreg, pat, REG_EXTENDED)) == 0)            
 {                                                                    
   printf("Compiling successful.\n");                                 
   int execret = -2;                                                  
   if((execret = regexec(&compreg, str, matchcnt, matches, 0)) == 0)  
   {                                                                  
     print_matches(matches);                                          
   }                                                                  
   else if(execret != 0)                                              
   {                                                                  
     printf("Regexec failed.\n");                                     
     size_t errbuffsz = regerror(execret, &compreg, 0, 0);            
     errbuff = malloc(errbuffsz);                                     
     memset(errbuff, '\0', errbuffsz);                                
     regerror(execret, &compreg, errbuff, errbuffsz);                 
     fprintf(stderr, "Regexec error: %s\n", errbuff);                 
   }                                                                  
 }                                                                    
 else                                                                 
 {                                                                    
   printf("Compiling failed.\n");                                     
   size_t errbuffsz = regerror(compret, &compreg, 0, 0);              
   errbuff = malloc(errbuffsz);                                       
   memset(errbuff, '\0', errbuffsz);                                  
   regerror(compret, &compreg, errbuff, errbuffsz);                   
   fprintf(stderr, "Regexec error: %s", errbuff);                     
 }                                                                    
 free(errbuff);                                                       
 errbuff = NULL;                                                      
 regfree(&compreg);                                                   
 return 0;                                                            
}
```

Here's the output of the above. My understanding of the pattern is that it has only one matching group. According to the docs, that means I should be presented with two populated `regmatch_t` elements: the first containing the entire string, and the second containing the group that was matched.

```
[chb]$ gcc -g -o foo foo.c                                                
[chb]$ ./foo  "^ROOM\s{1}NAME:\s{1}([[:alpha:]]{6})" "ROOM NAME: BriCol"
Trying to match with extended regex...                                                      
Compiling successful.                                                                       
Regexec successful.                                                                         
Match 0; Beginning:     0                                                                   
Match 0; End:           17                                                                  
Match 1; Beginning:     11                                                                  
Match 1; End:           17                                                                  
Match 2; Beginning:     0                                                                   
Match 2; End:           0                                                                   
Match 3; Beginning:     0                                                                   
Match 3; End:           0
```

I even commented out the `memset` that zeros out the array, thinking that the logic internal to the `regexec` command was somehow affected by it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want `regexec` to fill in unused array elements with -1, you need to tell it how many there are in the first place. Replace `matchcnt` with `MATCH_CNT` in this line:

```c
if((execret = regexec(&compreg, str, matchcnt, matches, 0)) == 0)
```

so it becomes

```c
if((execret = regexec(&compreg, str, MATCH_CNT, matches, 0)) == 0)
```

(and add the missing `int` before `compret = -2;`) and your program will work as expected:

```sh
$ ./549805 "^ROOM\s{1}NAME:\s{1}([[:alpha:]]{6})" "ROOM NAME: BriCol"
Trying to match with extended regex...
Compiling successful.
Regexec successful.
Match 0; Beginning: 0
Match 0; End:       17
Match 1; Beginning: 11
Match 1; End:       17
$
```

You should also initialise `errbuff` to `NULL`, to avoid calling `free()` with an undefined value (when `errbuff` is never initialised). And while you’re at it, check `malloc()`’s return value — allocations *can* fail.

Comment: Ah, cheers. I misunderstood the intent of the parameter. Also, I've corrected the lack of a type declaration in my example, as it was an error caused by excerpting.